# scala validate on model extra parameter which should not be saved in database

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.5

I have the following model:

```
case class ProcessStepTemplatesModel(
                                      id: Option[Int],
                                      title: String,
                                      createdat: String,
                                      updatedat: String,
                                      deadline: Option[Date],
                                      comment: Option[String],
                                      stepType: Int,
                                      deleted: Boolean,
                                      processtemplate: Option[Int])

object ProcessStepTemplatesModel {
  implicit val processStepFormat = Json.format[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]
}
```

I have an extra value `derived`. All data is sent via POST as JSON to my controller. When I validate the request with the model above this value is lost.

I need this value for the model to work with, but it shouldn't be persisted.

But if I add the value to the model I get an error from Scala slick.

Update:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, two options for you:

**1. Decouple your frontend representation from your actual model**

You could have a `ProcessStepTemplatesClientModel`, which has the extra field `derived` and is only used to validate the JSON input in the controller. After you are done with your business logic involving the `derived` field you convert the object to `ProcessStepTemplatesModel` and persist it in your database.

**2. Handle the field in your *-projection of your Slick table**

Include the derived field in your `ProcessStepTemplatesModel` class (assuming it is boolean, works with any other primitive):

```
case class ProcessStepTemplatesModel(
                                      id: Option[Int],
                                      title: String,
                                      createdat: String,
                                      updatedat: String,
                                      deadline: Option[Date],
                                      comment: Option[String],
                                      stepType: Int,
                                      deleted: Boolean,
                                      processtemplate: Option[Int],
                                      derived: Boolean)
```

And since you are using Slick as your database mapper you probably have a table representation for your `ProcessStepTemplatesModel`:

```
class ProcessStepTemplatesModelTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[ProcessTableTemplatesModel](tag, "PROCESS_TABLE_TEMPLATES_MODEL") {
    def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    ...
    def processtemplate = column[Option[Int]]("PROCESSTEMPLATE")

    def * = (id, ..., processtemplate) <> ( {
        tuple: (Int, ..., Option[Int]) => ProcessStepTemplatesModel(tuple._1, ..., tuple._9, derived = false)
      }, {
        ps: ProcessStepTemplatesModel => Some((ps.id, ..., ps.processtemplate))
      })
}
```

Don't include the derived field in the table definition and handle that case within the *-projection by handing a static value to the case class constructor to create the object from the tuple and just leave it out when creating the tuple from the object.

EDIT

As a response to your comment, a more concrete implementation of the *-projection, based on the `ProcessStepTemplatesModel` including `derived`:

```
def * : ProvenShape[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] = (id.?, title, createdat, updatedat, deadline, comment, stepType, deleted, processtemplate) <> ( {
        tuple: (Option[Int], String, String, String, Option[Data], Option[String], Int, Boolean, Option[Int]) => ProcessStepTemplatesModel(tuple._1, tuple._2, tuple._3, tuple._4, tuple._5, tuple._6, tuple._7, tuple._8, tuple._9, derived = false)
      }, {
        ps: ProcessStepTemplatesModel => Some((ps.id, ps.title, ps.createdat, ps.updatedat, ps.deadline, ps.comment, ps.stepType, ps.deleted, ps.processtemplate))
      })
```

Comment: yes I'm using slick. the *-projection looks like this. `def * : ProvenShape[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] = (id.?, title, createdat, updatedat, deadline, comment, stepType, deleted, processtemplate) <> ((ProcessStepTemplatesModel.apply _).tupled, ProcessStepTemplatesModel.unapply)`

How would I add the static value?

Comment: @Felix see Edit

Comment: thanks, I think close but an error still left postet a screenshot above

Comment: I changed the type in the projection from the Table to the Model, which likely caused the error

Comment: exactly thats the one I found as well ... some are still currend but probably comes from other destinations

Comment: I got errors on the insert functions. they all wanted the derived now

Comment: Can you share your complete model and table code, as well as your insert statements?

Comment: Problem is now when I want to access the derived its always empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147086/discussion-between-thwiegan-and-felix).

Comment: added some stuff in discussion

Comment: do you probably have time for a short skype session?